# Blender 2.8 - selecting parent and children at the same time

Tags: selection-tools, parent

In 2.8, I am unable to select Parent and children (in Outliner window) at the same time with Ctrl+ LMB. Is there anyway of doing this in 2.8?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do such a thing in 2.7x either? For me Ctrl+LMB does lasso select.

Comment: @gandalf3, edited my OP to clarify. The selection happens in the Outline window.

Comment: Ah. That works fine for me in 2.8 alpha 2 (b445d57ccf4), let me try a more recent version.

Comment: Still works in latest master as well. Are you clicking on the icon?